# Android DataBindingClasses are not updating immediately

Tags: android, layout, data-binding, android-databinding

**Problem:**

I'm working on a project having dataBinding integrated now whenever I create a new layout or add a view to an existing one it just not appear in binding object and **I even try rebuilding and cleaning the project but it doesn't work and I have to just restart the project or rename the layout file one or two times to update the** `BindingClass`. It is so annoying and consuming my important time.

**Code**

**build.grade**

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

**layout_file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View android:id="@+id/old_view_1" .../>
        <View android:id="@+id/old_view_2" .../>    

        <!-- New View -->
        <View android:id="@+id/new_view" .../>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**Activity/Fragment/Place where layout is used**

```
LayoutFileBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.layout_file);
binding.newView  
// here I get error cannot resolve (newView) until i restart project or rename layout file
```

Comment: It won't until and unless you rebuild project, because that's how **`Code generation `** works. you know how to rebuild project right? @Umer Khan

Comment: You can `rebuild` the project OR `close` the project and `re-open` it

Comment: Just `Rebuild Project` and you don't have to restart your project.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate caches? File -» Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes I know, I tried it but it's not working either.

Comment: Which version of android studio you're using? @UmerKhan

Comment: @UmerKhan just sync your project again

Answer (score 0):

[Data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) and platform support is still not so mature, I am using data binding from a long time, all the issues related to IDE are resolved but your problem happens most of the times with me too.

The most quick fix for me is

- **File > Close Project**
- **Open from recent**

This takes almost 5 second. and generates all newly added fields and layouts binding classes.

**It is faster than Rebuild or Restart AS.**